# SPSS variable width is zero

Tags: sql-server, odbc, spss

In SPSS Variable View Tab I have a String variable that has Width 0. Τhe data comes from Sql Server 2014 through ODBC (native 10). The field in database that corresponds to this variable has nvarchar(max). Why I have zero width in SPSS?

Comment: `0` is often used to denote "unlimited" length. I would suggest the `0` length here denotes that (though, technically a `nvarchar(MAX)` isn't unlimited, but around 1 billion characters)

Comment: I have another 3 same SPSS and the same variable has 5000 Width (!!!) and everything works. The problem is that I use the variable in a function (len()) and gives me error only in this installation of SPSS.

Answer (score 0):

IBM SPSS Statistics makes use of the IBM SPSS Statistics Data Access Pack (SDAP) for ODBC data sources.  In this case, I'd suggest using the SDAP version 8.1 and the "IBM SPSS OEM SQL Wire Protocol" ODBC driver.

Download "IBM SPSS Data Access Pack V8.1 Multiplatform English (CC7P4EN )" from the Passport Advantage portal where your obtained IBM SPSS Statistics.

When you use the "File -> Import data -> ODBC" wizard, check the SQL that is being created for this field and make sure it is appropriate.  It may be necessary for you to edit it and read this particular field in a different way.